# Custom tool error Failed to generate code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dataset-designer, customtool, custom-tools

Why this error is appearing?  I was just setting some default values in a dataset designer...  its second time that this is appearing...
"Custom tool error Failed to generate code. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown"

Comment: How much memory do you have on that system?

Comment: @Lasse: 1 GB on windows 7 x86

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found a way to regenerate codes.
In `Solution Explorer` right click on your DataSet and click `Run Custom Tool`.
I do it after closing and reopening VS2010...
Hope this help you, if you faced the problem...
good luck

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I changed the target framework from .net 4.5 to .net 4.8 on Visual Studio 2019.

For me was the Connections tag was looking for a global connection string or DatabaseProvinder that no longer existed.

If you don't need the connection anymore, You can just get rid of it.

Do that:

```
1- Right-click on the .xsd file chose open with and chose 'XML (Text) Editor', or another text editor that you prefer. 

2- Delete de content of the Connections tag and closes it.
```

After that, you will have something like this:

```
...
<DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
    <Connections />
    <Tables />
    <Sources />
  </DataSource>
...
```

[Reference / Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914840/failed-to-generate-code-error-when-compiling-a-asp-net-website-on-a-new-computer)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be dependent on the particular version of .NET. In my case, I could never get it to generate using 4.8–but it works perfectly with 4.8.1. Given that, try to upgrade your version of .NET.

Comment: @MoritzRingler: Good catch. Thank you for keeping me honest. I’ve made minor edits to the answer to avoid any confusion.