# Failed To Generate Code, Exception of Type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, xml, xsd

I'm Developing an asp.net Website that pulls Data from a MySQL database and generates reports using the built in Visual Studio Report Builder. 
The application compiles and debugs perfectly on local machine, but when uploaded to a Windows server Running IIS I get the following error:

> Parser Error 
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Failed to generate code. Exception of type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown.
>
> Source Error:
>
> (Line 1 is highlighted red on the error page)
>
> Line 1:  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
>
> Line 2:  `<xs:schema id="SensorReadingsDataSet" targetNamespace="http://imr.bi3.co/App_Code/SensorReadingsDataSet.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://imr.bi3.co/App_Code/SensorReadingsDataSet.xsd" xmlns="http://imr.bi3.co/App_Code/SensorReadingsDataSet.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">`
>
> Line 3:    `<xs:annotation>`
>
> Source File: /Dev/App_Code/SensorReadingsDataSet.xsd    Line: 1
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET >Version:4.0.30319.34212

I've Tried Running a custom tool on my DataSet as suggested here ([Custom tool error Failed to generate code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058446/custom-tool-error-failed-to-generate-code)) , but the option is greyed out in Visual Studio. I have not made any changes to the .xsd file, or to the structure of the database since it was created by VS.

I've also tried completely removing the dataset & reports and rebuilding them from scratch, which gives the same error still.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You just remind me the proper way to deploy an application!

I'm a lazy guy, I install Visual Studio in development machine as well as production machine.

I create a user name for the development machine and another user name for the production machine in the 'Team Project' of Visual Studio.

So every time I deploy the application, I just use get latest codes in the production machine and recompile.  of course in IIS of production machine, create a Web site points to the root of the project.

this avoid a number of problems as long as both machine with the same version of Visual studio and other related installed.